# How long does fresh salmon last in the freezer?

Tags: food-safety

I bought salmon 2 weeks ago, and left it in my freezer. Is it still safe to consume it? what about consuming it raw?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as long as food goes, 2 weeks in the freezer is not that long (assuming it was always in the freezer). So feel free to defrost it and enjoy your salmon.